# Open a Lua .love file in Vim

Tags: vim, lua, zip, love2d

So today I learned that Vim opens zip files for viewing and modification in an interface very similar to the directory browser.

Is there a way to open .love files accordingly? I tried setting the filetype:

`vim red-pill.love -c "set filetype=zip"`

...but no luck. It opens as a binary file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [zip.vim plugin docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_zip.html):

> Apparently there are a number of archivers who generate zip files that
>   don't use the .zip extension (.jar, .xpi, etc).  To handle such files,
>   place a line in your <.vimrc> file:
>
> > `au BufReadCmd *.jar,*.xpi call zip#Browse(expand("<amatch>"))`

Therefore, add this to your vimrc:

```
au BufReadCmd *.love call zip#Browse(expand("<amatch>"))
```